# Why is Bool "AnyObject" instead of "Any"?

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-playground

I have a simple question: Why does `Bool` qualify as `AnyObject`
According to Apple's documentation:

- ["`AnyObject` can represent an instance of any class type.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html)
- [`Bool` is a struct](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Bool_Structure/index.html)

So why does this statement pass?

```
let bool = true
let explicitBool: Bool = true

if (bool is AnyObject){
    print("I'm an object")
}

if (explicitBool is AnyObject){
    print("I'm still an object!")
}
```

[image]

Comment: For me, I get a warning that "`is` test is always true", assuming implicit bridging to Objective-C types.

Answer (score 8):

Because it's being bridged to an NSNumber instance.

> Swift automatically bridges certain native number types, such as Int
>   and Float, to NSNumber. [- Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C (Swift 2.2) - Numbers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH6-ID67)

Try this:

```
let test = bool as AnyObject
print(String(test.dynamicType))
```

Comment: I thought Foundation had to be imported for this to work?

Comment: @originaluser2 Me too, which is why I find this most curious. I'm not near a Mac to be able to test this though. Would you mind running OP's code + that code I pasted?

Comment: Hmm... seems to be a magical exception for playgrounds. When in playground, it prints `_NSCFBoolean` for the dynamic type with or without foundation import – although it doesn't allow you say `as AnyObject`, you have to use a conditional or forced downcast. When in a real project it works as expected (bridged to NSNumber with foundation import, unable to bridge without). Most curious.

Comment: Well, that's was the most unsatisfying result possible. Could it be some settings hidden in the playground files?

Comment: @originaluser2 I think this is due to implicit bridging to the Objective-C runtime behind-the-scenes in an Xcode Playground.

Comment: @JAL by why is the playground using the ObjC runtime at all?

Comment: Ask Apple.  Foundation does different things in the Mac release of Swift vs the open source release.

Comment: @AMomchilov It appears you are correct. [The value of bool.dynamicType in the playground is `_NSCFBoolean`](http://i.imgur.com/fxnw4qx.png)

Comment: @RembrandtQ.Einstein Note that [`__NSCFBoolean`](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/__NSCFBoolean.h) is just a subclass of `NSNumber`.

Comment: @JAL Right, that's why it validates the idea that Bool is being bridged to NSNumber. Why it's being bridged without any Foundation imports is the real question.

Comment: @RembrandtQ.Einstein it has to do with the runtime.  An Xcode Playground simulates an iPad runtime environment, which provides implicit bridging to Cocoa APIs.

Answer (score 4):

This behavior is due to the Playground runtime bridging to Objective-C/Cocoa APIs behind-the-scenes.  Swift version 3.0-dev (LLVM 8fcf602916, Clang cf0a734990, Swift 000d413a62) on Linux does not reproduce this behavior, with or without Foundation imported

```
let someBool = true
let someExplicitBool: Bool = true

print(someBool.dynamicType) // Bool
print(someExplicitBool.dynamicType) // Bool

print(someBool is AnyObject) // false
print(someExplicitBool is AnyObject) // fase
```

[Try it online.](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/575847aef25f783d3ee24e6a)

Comment: Is this a bug? I can't tell

Comment: @AMomchilov I don't think so.  I think this occurs only on Mac due to the implicit bridging of `Bool` to `ObjCBool` and `NSNumber`.